# Where can I change the port of a Web Site Project (WCF) in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013, port, vs-web-site-project

For `Web Site Projects` in Visual Studio 2010 the `port` could be changed in the properties after setting `use dynamic ports` to false. This option not present in Visual Studio 2013. Can the port there only be changed directly in the SLN file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is as suspected. The `ports` have to be changed in the SLN file and the `URL` in the web.config

**SLN File of the solution:**

```
VWDPort = "xxx"
```

**Web.config of the website:**

```
endpoint address="http://....."
```

Comment: Ok for the web.config, but in the sln file I haven't that option. I've found something similar in the csproj file:


          <DevelopmentServerPort>56179</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:56179/</IISUrl>

Comment: @PieroAlberto did the chaning in the csproj file work?

Comment: yes, it worked. I had to do this changes because I have done "copy&paste" of a previous project to create another one and it had still the old options. Editing the **csproj** file has solved the problem.

Comment: @PieroAlberto I would post it as answer

Comment: so, have I to answer at the question?

Comment: @PieroAlberto why not, it seems to be helpful for a problem like I described :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution worked for me is:

**Web.config of the website:**

```
endpoint address="http://....."
```

**csproj File of the project (or vbproj):**

```
<DevelopmentServerPort>56179</DevelopmentServerPort> 
<IISUrl>localhost:56179/</IISUrl>
```

Editing these parameters make you able to change the port as you want.